# Preloader in Visualforce page and align text in the center

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css, html

I have added a circle by using the HTML SVG tag in a VF page.

When i render that page as PDF, it's not showing that circle. Is there another way to add small circle but also to be visible when rendering as PDF?

I used image after trying this. I've put small image of that circle and text in front of that circle, but it's not aligning properly. I want to set that text center of the circle. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered many "translation errors" when rendering HTML as a PDF.  I agree using an image is a great option.  Check out the `vertical-align` CSS attribute (specifically `vertical-align:middle`)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp